# Configure ASP.NET Web API to send empty tags for null values

Tags: web-services, asp.net-web-api, xmlserializer

I am new to ASP.NET Web API.

I have configured my application to use XMLSerializer as

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer
                                                                    = true;
```

For Simplicity say my Controller returns an instance of class Account

```
public class Account
{
  public int AccountId {get;set;}

  public string AccountName {get;set;} 

  public string AccountNickName {get;set;}
}
```

I get this when as XML response when *AccountNickName* (which is optional) has a value

```
<Account>
 <AccountId>1</AccountId>
 <AccountName>ABAB</AccountName>
 <AccountNickName>My Account</AccountNickName>
</Account>
```

I get this as XML response when *AccountNickName* (which is optional) is `null`

```
<Account>
 <AccountId>1</AccountId>
 <AccountName>ABAB</AccountName>
</Account>
```

**the XML output skips the *AccountNickName* tag if the value is null.**

My question are :

1. How do I configure the serializer to send a closed tag instead of skipping the property
2. AND Is there a way to configure this on the application level rather than on the class level

**Update:**

I know that you can configure the JsonFormatter by using a [JsonSerializerSetting](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Using-JSONNET-with-ASPNET-b2423706), Can you somehow do this with XMLSerializer as well?

I DO NOT want to add Attributes / Decorators on the Class.

Comment: This seems to be a performance improvement, instead of taking a step back on performance I'd just adapt my client accordingly. Provided that you have control of the client.

Comment: Why does the client care about empty tags vs. self-closing elements?

Comment: It is not about empty or self closing. The tags are not present in the  output!

Answer (score 1):

Did a quick test here and I found that if you don't do this:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer                                                                   = true;
```

The null value will get serialized as an actual element by default.

Is there another reason why you explicitly wanted to configure this? Setting that value to "true" will cause Web API to use the "XmlSerializer" instead of the "DataContractSerialier" class which is the default.

Web API will return XML for a given request if the request includes the appropriate "Content-Type" header indicating the desire for an XML response.

Comment: yes, I did not want DataContract attributes on classes and the default DataContractSerializer was adding dp4 namespaces to my collections.. the example given here is kindof simplified

Comment: "I did not want DataContract attributes on classes" =>  note that DataContractSerializer has POCO type support...

Comment: even if i add this mlserializer to true, it still doesnt return null xml elements.

Answer (score 0):

The XmlSerializer will write out the property even when it's null if you put this on your property:  `[XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]`.

```
public class Account
{
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public string AccountName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
    public string AccountNickName { get; set; }
}
```

Xml:

```
<Account xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <AccountId>123</AccountId>
    <AccountName>John Doe</AccountName>
    <AccountNickName xsi:nil="true"/>
</Account>
```

Comment: Is there a way to configure this on the application level rather than on the class level?

Comment: You could use set the `IsNullable` to `true` using `XmlAttributesOverrides` and then add the `XmlAttributesOverrides` to the to the serializer in `config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SetSerializer`, but this only works if your attribute is not a primitive type (i.e. `AccountNickName` is  string in your code snippet).