# Select which fields to serialize to XML from a Web API call

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have five tables who are used to generate a response for a Web API call. My code will display all field, also those I didn't set, in the XML output.

How do I display only relevant fields without any duplicate fields?

This is my class file:

```
public class Posts 
{
    public  Suburb suburb { get; set; }
    public SubRegion subRegion { get; set; }
    public SubRegionDeliveryTime subRegionDeliveryTime { get; set; }
    public DeliveryTime deliveryTime { get; set; }
    public DeliveryPeriod deliveryPeriod { get; set; }
}
```

This is my API Controller source code.

```
public IEnumerable<Posts> Get(int pcode, string SuburbName = "")
{
    using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {

       var Location1 = (from su in db.TLCSuburb.AsEnumerable()
                        where su.name.Contains(SuburbName) ||
                        su.postcode == pcode
                        join Subr in db.TLCSubRegion on
                        su.SubRegionID equals Subr.SubregionID
                        join srdt in db.TLCSubRegionDeliveryTime on
                        Subr.SubregionID equals srdt.SubregionID
                        join DT in db.TLCDeliveryTime on
                        srdt.DeliveryTimeId equals DT.DeliveryTimeId
                        join DP in db.TLCDeliveryPeriod on
                        DT.DeliveryPeriodID equals DP.DeliveryPeriodID
                        orderby Subr.SubregionID

                        select new Posts
                        {
                            suburb = new Suburb()

                              { 
                                name = su.name,
                                postcode = su.postcode,
                                AuState = su.AuState,
                                Latitude = su.Latitude,
                                Longitude = su.Longitude

                            },
                                  //deliveryTime = DT.DeliveryDay,

                                  deliveryTime = new DeliveryTime()
                                  {

                                      DeliveryDay = DT.DeliveryDay,
                                  },

                                  deliveryPeriod = new DeliveryPeriod()
                                   {
                                       PeriodType = DP.PeriodType
                                   },


                                  subRegion = new SubRegion()
                                  {
                                      CloseDayId = Subr.CloseDayId,
                                      SubregionName = Subr.SubregionName
                                  }

                        }).ToList();

    string subReName = "";
    int poscode;
    foreach (var item in Location1)
    {
       var aus = item.suburb.AuState;
       poscode = item.suburb.postcode;
       subReName = item.subRegion.SubregionName;
    }

    var loc = Location1.ToList();
    // return null;
    return loc.ToList();
    }
}
```

My output should be this format only:

```
<Posts>
<name>BLUES POINT</name>
<postcode>2060</postcode>
<DeliveryDay>Monday</DeliveryDay>
<PeriodType>weekly</PeriodType>
<AuState>NSW</AuState>
<Latitude>-33.8495688</Latitude>
<Longitude>151.2035053</Longitude>
<SubregionName>Sydney - Nth Shore - Lower</SubregionName>
<CloseDayId>1</CloseDayId>
</Posts>
```

Comment: Only public variables get serialized.  So if you don't want an object serialized then make it private.

Comment: All data fields are public

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Introduce a Data Transfer Object so you don't expose your data layer from your API layer. This approach allows you to change the data layer without having to alter your API:

```
public class LocationDTO
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
    // ...
}

// ...

return locations.Select(l => new LocationDTO
{
    Name = l.suburb.Name,
    PostCode = l.suburb.PostCode,
    // ...
}).ToList()
```

Using attributes on the LocationDTO you can then select which fields get serialized, when and how.

Or you can [alter the serializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13883031/configure-asp-net-web-api-to-send-empty-tags-for-null-values). WebAPI uses DataContractSerializer for XML, which emits null and default values by default. If you use XmlSerializer, the API will omit empty and default fields.

Comment: Thank you for your code. I have question, how can access Name = suburb.Name, because Location loop has already closed (suburb.Name)

Comment: Thank you, now I got another error saying "Error 3 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<TLcWebAPIVer5.Models.LocationDTO>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TLcWebAPIVer5.Models.Posts>'."

Comment: Yeah you've got to change the method's return type too.

Comment: The data types are double,int,string. How do I change the method's return type

Comment: @Rob of the method declaration `public IEnumerable<Posts> Get(int pcode, string SuburbName = "")`, the return type is `IEnumerable<Posts>`.

Comment: I have already added top public IEnumerable<Posts> in my code. Do I need add somewhere else?

Comment: And that's the wrong return type. You're returning a `IEnumerable<LocationDTO>` now.

Comment: I am sorry about that now return area is  locations.Select(l => new IEnumerable<LocationDTO>?

Comment: You need to change the return type of the method to `IEnumerable<LocationDTO>` where it now says `IEnumerable<Post>`.